# how can I find the longest path from one point to another point in a 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this code to find the longest path in a 2d array from "s" to "t" and return the length of the longest path. I used recursion function finding() , but it doesn't work well. How can I fix it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner  sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String[][] park=new String[n][n];
        LinkedList<Integer> ways=new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                park[i][j]=sc.next();
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        LinkedList<Integer[]> Visited=new LinkedList<>();
        int fx=0;
        int fy=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                if(park[i][j].equals("s")){
                    fy=i;
                    fx=j;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(finding(park,fx,fy,Visited));

    }
    public static int finding(String[][] park,int x,int y,LinkedList<Integer[]> visited){
        int x_=x;
        int y_=y;
        int length=0;
        LinkedList<Integer[]> neighbors=new LinkedList<>();
        if(isValid(x+1,y,park.length,park)){
            Integer[] neighbor=new Integer[2];
            neighbor[0]=y;
            neighbor[1]=x+1;
            neighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
        if(isValid(x-1,y,park.length,park)){
            Integer[] neighbor=new Integer[2];
            neighbor[0]=y;
            neighbor[1]=x-1;
            neighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
        if(isValid(x,y+1,park.length,park)){
            Integer[] neighbor=new Integer[2];
            neighbor[0]=y+1;
            neighbor[1]=x;
            neighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
        if(isValid(x,y-1,park.length,park)){
            Integer[] neighbor=new Integer[2];
            neighbor[0]=y-1;
            neighbor[1]=x;
            neighbors.add(neighbor);
        }
        if(park[y_][x_].equals("t")){
            return 1;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<neighbors.size();i++){
            if(!visited.contains(neighbors.get(i))){
                y_=neighbors.get(i)[0];
                x_=neighbors.get(i)[1];
                Integer[] A=new Integer[2];
                A[0]=y_;
                A[1]=x_;
                visited.add(A);
                length+=finding(park,x_,y_,visited);
            }
        }
        return length;
    }
    public static boolean isValid(int x,int y,int n,String[][] park){
        if((x<n && x>=0) && (y<n && y>=0)){
            if(!park[y][x].equals("$")){return true;}
            return  false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    }
```

3

s # #

$ # #

t # #

this matris is an example of the 2d array which it should search for it's longest path from s to t.

I get stackoverflow exception when I run it.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);` at the start of your finding method.  That should reveal the cause of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "Find the longest path ..." ?  From your code and example, we can guess what you mean, but we shouldn't have to guess. Your question should clearly describe that.  This and its links might help: [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .